# What is the paste deploy uri syntax?

Tags: python, paster

Paste Deploy can reference code with uris such as

```
[section]
use = egg:FooBar#baz
```

What is the full syntax for these uris?

Answer (score 2):

Those URIs are [fully detailed in the documentation](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#basic-usage). It boils down to `config:`, `egg:`, and prefix-less URIs that point to other sections.